# CRM 2011 JScript retrieveMultiple throwing Bad Request Error

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, jscript

I am trying to retrieve multiple records using `oData` on Contact form but it's throwing `Bad Request` error. Can anyone suggest me why it's happening.

Thanks in advance

**JScript**

```
// Retrieving multiple connections with accound ID as Record2Id.
function myFunction
{
    var contId = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();

    retrieveMultiple("ConnectionSet", "ConnectionId", "Record2Id eq '" + contId + "'",    successCallbackConnections, errorCallbackConnections, true);
}

function successCallbackConnections(data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest)
{
    for(i=0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        alert(data[i].RoleName);
    }       
}

function errorCallbackConnections(XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(errorThrown);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
function myFunction
{
    var contId = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();

    retrieveMultiple("ConnectionSet", "ConnectionId,Record2Id", "Record2Id/Id eq guid'" + contId + "'",    successCallbackConnections, errorCallbackConnections, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `filter` is missing!!
Try this:

```
retrieveMultiple("ConnectionSet", "?$filter=YourAttributeHere eq '" + contId + "'", successCallbackConnections, errorCallbackConnections, true);
```